# How can I use an hbox inside a TikZ environment for text dimension measurement?

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxes

I'm trying to use an `\hbox` to measure the dimensions of a certain text. This is working in normal text as in the following example:

```
\setbox37=\hbox{this is a text that I want to measure}
text width is \the\wd37, text heigh is \the\ht37\\
text contents: \box37
```

The output is correct as I expected:

*text width is 159.63913pt, text heigh is 6.94444pt

text contents: this is a text that I want to measure*

However, when trying to do the same inside a TikZ environmnet, the box I'm using is not assigned the text I pass to `\hbox`, instead I gets empty box with zero width & height. Here is the code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \setbox37=\hbox{this is a text that I want to measure}
  \node[draw] at (0,0) {text width is \the\wd37, text heigh is \the\ht37};
  \node[draw] at (0,-1) {text contents is \box37};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And here is the output:

[image: output]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

PGF/TikZ takes care that non-drawing material inside its picture environments is not typeset. The whole environment is stored in a box which is later discarded while (IMHO) the drawing commands draw in a different box which is then typeset.
This alone wouldn't be an issue for your code, but PGF/TikZ also sets the font to `\nullfont` as well redefines `\selectfont` to suppress font changes. Only for node contents and other "official" text like labels the font is restored.

Therefore the text in your box can't be typeset and the box is empty. A trace with `\tracingall` gives you the following messages:

```
{\setbox}
{the letter t}
Missing character: There is no t in font nullfont!
{the letter h}
Missing character: There is no h in font nullfont!
{the letter i}
...
```

You need to either set the box outside the picture environment or restore the font. You can use the `pgfinterruptpicture` environment to escape to a normal typesetting state with font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newbox\mybox

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \setbox\mybox=\hbox{\pgfinterruptpicture this is a text that I want to measure\endpgfinterruptpicture}
  \node[draw] at (0,0) {text width is \the\wd\mybox, text heigh is \the\ht\mybox};
  \node[draw] at (0,-1) {text contents is \box\mybox};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively you could restore `\selectfont` and the font manually just for the box content:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newbox\mybox
\let\origselectfont\selectfont
\newcommand{\restorefont}{%
    \let\selectfont\origselectfont
    \normalfont
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \setbox\mybox=\hbox{\restorefont this is a text that I want to measure}
  \node[draw] at (0,0) {text width is \the\wd\mybox, text heigh is \the\ht\mybox};
  \node[draw] at (0,-1) {text contents is \box\mybox};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### Some other notes:

- You shouldn't use plain numbers for boxes. Box #37 might be used by some other code. My first guess was that TikZ uses it and sets it to be empty :-)
- AFAIK with the `\setbox` primitive there might be issues with color changes. Use `\sbox\mybox{<content>}` instead which handles them.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the reason; I knew how to solve the problem using `\global\setbox` but didn't know why it was necessary to do so.

Comment: @Martin thanks for the explanation. using `pgfinterruptpicture` works for me.

Comment: I find it miraculous that this problem, which I thought was too obscure to ever have been asked, has not only been asked but been answered so well (and just one month ago).

Comment: Also, the PGF manual says that `{pgfinterruptpicture}` is intended for use *inside* a box.  If you put it there, you no longer need to use `\global` (I tested this and it works).