# How to right align a table in a tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

I currently have set up a command that draws a box with a shadow and some text inside that box. I want it to have a minimum-width, but when I set it, the table is now aligned in the center of the box when the table is smaller than the boxes width. I'd like it to be right-aligned. Here's the current setup:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{color}

\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0, 0.58, 0.85}

\newcommand*\invhead[1]{\sffamily{\color{myblue}\footnotesize{\textbf{#1}}}}

\tikzstyle{shadedbox} = [
  draw=black,
  shade,
  top color=white,
  bottom color=bottom,
  drop shadow={
    top color=black,
    bottom color=black,
    shadow xshift=2pt,
    shadow yshift=-2pt,
  },
  thin,
  rectangle,
  inner sep=2pt,
  inner ysep=2pt
]

\newcommand*\monobox[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \definecolor{top}{RGB}{250,250,250}
    \definecolor{bottom}{RGB}{235,235,235}
    \node [shadedbox, minimum width=3.1cm] (box) {
      \begin{tabular}{r}
        \invhead{\scriptsize #1}\\
        \footnotesize{#2}\\
      \end{tabular}
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\setkomavar{fromname}{TestCompany}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{37 Test Road, Someplace\\Somewhere, 6020\\Australia}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{+61 123 1234 1234}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{accounts@testcompany.com}
\setkomavar{signature}{TestCompany}
\setkomavar{invoice}[Invoice number]{1234}
\setkomavar{date}[Issue Date]{\today}
\setkomavar{customer}[Account number]{1234567}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{%
  Mr Nick Sandford\\
  23 Test St\\
  Somewhere, Someplace\\
  Australia
}

\opening{Dear Nick Sandford,}
\monobox{Test Box}{\$0.00}
\closing{Regards}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

I call it like `\monobox{This Bill}{\$20.00}`. This is what it looks like when it is rendered:

[image: boxes]

Hopefully I'm not doing anything too wrong :).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please always add a full but [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. Especially with TikZ it is important to know which libraries you are using. Also I don't know `middle right` and the PGF/TikZ manual doesn't mentioned it either.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Oh, whoops - that wasn't supposed to be there, it was me randomly trying combinations of words to hopefully align it. Needless to say, it didn't work. I'll add a minimal working example in a second.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Hopefully the example outputs successfully now :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To right align text in a node you must set the `text width` and the the `align` options on it. In your example code you could modify the `monobox` command to look like this:

```
\newcommand*\monobox[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \definecolor{top}{RGB}{250,250,250}
    \definecolor{bottom}{RGB}{235,235,235}
    \node [shadedbox, minimum width=3.1cm, text width=3.1cm, align=right] (box) {
      \begin{tabular}{r}
        \invhead{\scriptsize #1}\\
        \footnotesize{#2}\\
      \end{tabular}
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

The result:

[image: right aligned node text]

**Update:** after Martin and Peter's comments I modfied the code, this should work regardless of the width of the input

```
\newcommand*\monobox[2]{%
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \definecolor{top}{RGB}{250,250,250}
    \definecolor{bottom}{RGB}{235,235,235}
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\mylen}{max(width("#1"),3.1cm)}
    \node [shadedbox, minimum width=3.1cm, text width=\mylen, align=right] (box) {
      \begin{tabular}{r}
        \invhead{\scriptsize #1}\\
        \footnotesize{#2}\\
      \end{tabular}
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Remaining problem is that the text is set using `invhead` and `scriptsize` and for some reason I can't get TikZ to accept these in the `width` operation. The manual says "protecting" it with a `\noexpand` should do the trick, but it doesn't. Therefore too much space is allocated. Anybody have any idea how this can be fixed?

**Edit:** after Martin's proposal to use a box, why is this not working?

**Extra bonus-edit:** Martin explained on chat and in this answer (Thank you Martin `:)`): [How can I use an hbox inside a TikZ environment for text dimension measurement?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18602/how-can-i-use-an-hbox-inside-a-tikz-environment-for-text-dimension-measurement/18606#18606)

```
\newcommand*\monobox[2]{%
  \newsavebox\mybox
  \sbox{\mybox}{%
    \begin{tabular}{r}
      \invhead{\scriptsize #1}\\
      \footnotesize{#2}\\
    \end{tabular}
  }
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \definecolor{top}{RGB}{250,250,250}
    \definecolor{bottom}{RGB}{235,235,235}
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\mywd}{max(3.1cm,\wd\mybox)}
    \node [shadedbox, minimum width=3.1cm, text width=\mywd, align=right] (box) {
      \usebox{\mybox}
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

This produces a box of the correct size, using the `\mywd` macro ensures that the text is also right aligned if it's shorter than `3.1cm`.

Comment: I had the same idea, but this doesn't give a *minimal* width, but fixes it. If the table content is wider it will stick out from the box.

Comment: That is correct, each box will be at least `3.1 cm` in this case. We could make a macro that takes the text that is passed to `monobox` as an argument, determines its width and then uses the minimum of that width and `3.1 cm` as the value for `text width`.

Comment: I think this is sufficient, The boxes should be larger than the content every time. Thanks!

Comment: @wh1t3 Good solution. You could improve the user interface by giving the user an optional argument in monoblock to set the width.

Comment: I belive that you are missing a `;` following the `}` before `\end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: @PeterGrill: Yes, excellent! So is the example in the OP's question. I have modified the code, it appears the `"`'s are also necessary.

Comment: I would box the full `tabular` instead and use its width (`\wd`), then `\usebox` inside the node.

Comment: If you want to provide more flexibility in the user interface see how I have provided optional parameters in [new command for a height flexible rect](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33730/new-command-for-a-height-flexible-rect/33772#33772)

Comment: @MartinScharrer: I tried it, but couldn't get it to work... The `usebox` in the node doesn't seem to produce the table. I will add what I did in the answer, perhaps you could tell me what is wrong? :)

@PeterGrill: I just took the `monobox` command from the MWE the OP provided, judging by how he is using commands and TikZ styles, I assume he knows how to pass arguments to the TikZ options as well. Nice answer though, +1 :)