# New command for a height-flexible rect

Tags: macros, boxes

I'm trying to create a command that will take in one argument and create a rectangle around that number of empty lines. I have the following:

```
\newcommand{\putansbox}[1]{
 \framebox[\textwidth]{
    \vspace{\the\baselineskip}
 }
}
```

It only creates one line though. How can I use the `#1` in here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\framebox` is a horizontal box, so you cannot add vertical space to it, without using a vertical box like `\parbox` inside. Here is another solution with an invisible rule:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\putansbox}[1]{%
  \framebox[\textwidth]{\rule{0pt}{#1\baselineskip}}
}

\begin{document}
\noindent\putansbox{5}
\end{document}
```

And if you don't want the box to break the line width, you may use, e.g.

```
\newcommand{\putansbox}[1]{%
  \framebox[\dimexpr \linewidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep\relax]{%
    \rule{0pt}{#1\baselineskip}%
  }%
}
```

To not forget the answer to your question: You may use the #1 as a prefix of `\baselineskip` because `\baselineskip` is a length and lengths may be used like units.

Comment: +1 for the alternative. I was doing all sort of weird stuff with forloops and whatnot.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get fancier, you could also use something like `mdframed`, or `tikz`.

Here is a `tikz` solution using `shadedbox` from [How to right align a table in a tikz picture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33727/how-to-right-align-a-table-in-a-tikz-picture/33728#33728), so if you like this solution, please up vote that answer.

The `\putansbox` defined here accept an optional first parameter that provides you the option of using the full power of `tikz` to modify what you want.  Refer to the TikZ documentation for more details and options, but the options that are shown in this MWE include:

- specify a top/bottom color for the shading: `bottom color=yellow!10, top color=red!10`
- using rounded corners: `rounded corners=15pt`
- adjusting the line width: `line width=1pt`
- adjusting the line color: `draw=blue`
- adjusting the width of the box: `text width=0.6\linewidth`
- adjusting the line style: `densely dotted`

See the TikZ documentation for more options.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\tikzstyle{shadedbox} = [
  text width=0.97\linewidth,
  draw=black,
  shade, top color=white, bottom color=white,
  drop shadow={
    top color=black,
    bottom color=black,
    shadow xshift=2pt,
    shadow yshift=-2pt,
  },
  rectangle,
]

\newcommand*\putansbox[2][]{%
  \noindent%
  \begin{tikzpicture}%
    \node [shadedbox, #1] (box) {%
    \vspace {#2\baselineskip}%
    };%
  \end{tikzpicture}\\%
}


\begin{document}

\putansbox{5}

\putansbox[bottom color=yellow!10]{5}

\putansbox[rounded corners=15pt, line width=1pt, draw=blue]{5}

\putansbox[text width=0.6\linewidth, top color=red!10, densely dotted]{5}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks ... I guess this is a little over my head and also a little bit of an overkill. I'm designing this for print and want to keep it simple. Good intro to tikz though.

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution based on `\phantombox{<width>}{<height>}{<depth>}` from my `adjustbox` package. It creates an empty box with the given dimensions, then use `\frame` to draw a tight frame around it. I also added some other macros to add some separation between the surrounding text.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newcommand{\putansbox}[1]{%
    \par\medskip\par\noindent
    \frame{\phantombox{\linewidth}{#1\baselineskip}{\dp\strutbox}}%
    \par\smallskip\par
}


\begin{document}

text
\putansbox{5}
text

\end{document}
```