# Why do some arguments in a macro need to be preceded by \noexpand?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, programming, expansion

I keep on studying the use of nested tikzpicture environments (sorry) and I discover the next problem. I'm not sure but it sounds like a problem with "fragile" commands. Perhaps,  the problem is the nested environments but I do not think so because the code  works in many cases.
It's very strange, that `$\mathbf{\Pi}$` gives no problem  while `\textbf{textbf}` is catastrophic !.

In the next code, I use the macro `\place` to  put an object ( some tex's code) with the help of a node. I simplify a little bit the chain of macros but I keep the essential things.

**Code** I work with pgf 2.1 CVS

Uncomment the line

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}

\makeatletter
\def\place{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\place@i}{\place@i[]}}%
\def\place@i[#1]#2(#3)#{\place@ii[#1]{#2}(#3)}%
\def\place@ii[#1]#2(#3)#4{% 
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
  \path (0,0)--(#3);
  \node[anchor=#1,rotate=#2] at (#3) {#4};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}% 

\begin{document}

Baseline%
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[help lines] (0,-4) grid (5,1);
 \place[west]{0}(1,-2){$ \frac{2}{3}$} 
 \place[west]{-30}(2,-3){$\mathbf{\Pi}$} 
\end{tikzpicture}% 

% uncomment the next line with \place to see the problem
\begin{tikzpicture}
 %\place[west]{0}(4,0){\textbf{textbf}} 
\end{tikzpicture} 

% \noexpand resolves the problem 
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \place[west]{0}(2,0){\noexpand\textbf{textbf}} 
\end{tikzpicture}  

\end{document}
```

**Results**

[image]

but if I don't use `\noexpand`:

[image]

**What kind of problem I encountered?**

Comment: It works with the TeX Live version.

Comment: @egreg do you have uncomment the line ?

Comment: @Altermundus: A small explanation is given here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18602/how-can-i-use-an-hbox-inside-a-tikz-environment-for-text-dimension-measurement You see that your solution doens't provide a bold output

Comment: @MarcoDaniel yes the link is interesting, I need to test some ideas in this answer. How I can transform my code to avoid this problem?

Comment: @Altermundus You're right. PGF doesn't like changing fonts, while math doesn't harm. I suggest you to use Martin's way of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Marco,thanks for the link to the answer [of Martin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18602/how-can-i-use-an-hbox-inside-a-tikz-environment-for-text-dimension-measurement) and  Martin thanks for the explanation  using pgfinterruptpicture

The next code seems to remove the problem

```
\newbox\mybox   

\makeatletter
\def\place{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\place@i}{\place@i[]}}%
\def\place@i[#1]#2(#3)#{\place@ii[#1]{#2}(#3)}%
\def\place@ii[#1]#2(#3)#4{%
 %\setbox\mybox=\hbox{\pgfinterruptpicture #4\endpgfinterruptpicture}            
 \sbox\mybox{\pgfinterruptpicture#4\endpgfinterruptpicture}% from Martin Scharrer and egreg
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
     \path (0,0)--(#3);
     \node[anchor=#1,rotate=#2] at (#3) {\box\mybox};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%
```

Comment: I'd use `\sbox\mybox{\pgfinterruptpicture#4\endpgfinterruptpicture}` which is color safe.

Comment: @egreg Please, can you explain your comment ? The subtlety seems to be interesting ! I used Martin's code but I saw after your comment, the last line : `\sbox\mybox{<content>}` instead of`\setbox\mybox=\hbox{...` I don't understand why !

Comment: `\sbox\mybox{...}` takes some supplementary precautions against possible color leaking that the primitive `\setbox\mybox=\hbox{...}` can't.

Comment: ok thanks. I need to find a link about this. It's amazing what you should know to make a correct code ! This site is incredible  to find answer but sometimes it's difficult to find the good link. Fortunately some users have a good memory