# How do I assess the length of text within a pgffor \foreach loop

Tags: lengths, pgfmath, pgffor

I would like to be able to write something like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newlength\aelengtha
\newlength\aelengthb
\newlength\aelengthc
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (Q) at (0,0);

\foreach \myn [count=\myc from=1]
              in {apple,
                  orange,
                  this is a long line,
                  short}
{
  \pgfextra{%%
    \settowidth\aelengthb{\texttt{\myn}}
    \ifdim\aelengtha<\aelengthb
      \global\aelengtha=\aelengthb
      \typeout{==>resetting=\the\aelengtha}
    \fi}
  \typeout{==>\the\aelengthb}
  \node[anchor=base west,font=\ttfamily] at ($(Q)+(0,-\myc\baselineskip)$) {this \myn\ is an item};
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But, for some reason, no lengths are actually calculated.  So I tried to find a `pgf` solution and came up with the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newlength\aelengtha
\newlength\aelengthb
\newlength\aelengthc
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (Q) at (0,0);

\foreach \myn [count=\myc from=1]
              in {apple,
                  orange,
                  this is a long line,
                  short}
{
  \pgfmathparse{width("\myn")}
  \aelengthb=\pgfmathresult pt
  \pgfextra{%%
    \ifdim\aelengtha<\aelengthb
      \global\aelengtha=\aelengthb
      \typeout{==>resetting=\the\aelengtha}
    \fi}
  \typeout{==>\the\aelengthb}
  \node[anchor=base west,font=\ttfamily] at ($(Q)+(0,-\myc\baselineskip)$) {this is \myn\ an item};
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\typeout{==>\the\aelengtha}

\end{document}
```

But this isn't really calculating the width of the text I want to work with.  What I would like to do is write something like

```
\pgfmathparse{width("\texttt{\myn}")}
```

But that results in an error:

```
! Argument of \XC@definec@lor has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.28     }

?
```

I've also tried:

```
\pgfmathparse{width("\noexpand\texttt{\myn}")}
```

without any luck either.

How can I make a calculation of the *true* textwidth that's being formatted within the `\foreach` loop?

**UPDATE**

There's something about the `tikzpicture` environment that seems to dislike or prevent my code for measuring the width of text from working.  For example, everything compiles fine in the example below (sans `tikzpicture`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newlength\aelengtha
\newlength\aelengthb
\newlength\aelengthc
\begin{document}

\foreach \myn [count=\myc from=1]
              in {apple,
                  orange,
                  this is a long line,
                  short}
{
  \settowidth\aelengthb{\texttt{\myn}}%%
  \ifdim\aelengtha<\aelengthb
    \global\aelengtha=\aelengthb
    \typeout{==>Length A=\the\aelengtha : recalculated}
  \fi
  \typeout{==>length B=\the\aelengthb}
}

\typeout{==>length A=\the\aelengtha : Final}

\the\aelengtha

\end{document}
```

So, this lead me to consider writing the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newlength\aelengtha
\newlength\aelengthb
\newlength\aelengthc
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (Q) at (0,0);

\foreach \myn [count=\myc from=1]
              in {apple,
                  orange,
                  this is a long line,
                  short}
{
  \pgfinterruptpicture
    \settowidth\aelengthb{\texttt{\myn}}%%
    \ifdim\aelengtha<\aelengthb
      \global\aelengtha=\aelengthb
      \typeout{==>Length A=\the\aelengtha : Resetting}%%
    \fi
   \typeout{==>Length B=\the\aelengthb}%%
  \endpgfinterruptpicture
  \node[anchor=base west,font=\ttfamily] at ($(Q)+(0,-\myc\baselineskip)$) {\myn};
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which works!  But, the `tikz` manual specifically says that `\pgfinterruptpicture` is not meant to be used in this fashion.

Apart from getting a *valid* working example, I would *also* like to understand why my original example above fails to work as expected.

Comment: I just updated the question to reflect that I'm not necessarily able to calculate the width of the formatted text from the width of the node.

Comment: Also, I had to resort to using `\pgfextra` to be able to compare the lengths I was working with.  But, this seems to be contrary to what the manual says about the use of `\pgfextra` being restricted to inside a path.

Comment: Does `[font=\ttfamily]
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\mywidth}{width("\myn")};` do what you want?

Comment: @cfr It might.  But I'd be much more interested in understanding why the `\settowidth` code of the first example fails and why I seem to need the `\pgfextra` when I'm not in a path construction.

Comment: Hmmm... Yes. Of course, you don't need `\pgfextra` if you use `\pgfmathsetmacro`...

Answer (score 2):

This is what I wound up going with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newlength\aelengtha
\newlength\aelengthb
\newlength\aelengthc
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (Q) at (0,0);

\foreach \myn [count=\myc from=1]
              in {apple,
                  orange,
                  this is a long line,
                  short}
{
    \settowidth\aelengthb{\pgfinterruptpicture\texttt{\myn}\endpgfinterruptpicture}%%
    \ifdim\aelengtha<\aelengthb
      \global\aelengtha=\aelengthb
      \typeout{==>Length A=\the\aelengtha : Resetting}%%
    \fi
   \typeout{==>Length B=\the\aelengthb}%%

  \node[anchor=base west,font=\ttfamily] at ($(Q)+(0,-\myc\baselineskip)$) {\myn};
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Explanations for why this code works can be found at [\settowidth problem in tikz and in groups](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56405/22413) and at [How can I use an hbox inside a TikZ environment for text dimension measurement?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18606/22413)